# How to Stop Node.Js Process Started by Bazel

Tags: node.js, terminal, bazel

```
bazel run //services/server
```

Starts a Node.Js Server. But after the server started, I can't stop it by pressing `CTRL` + `C`. How can I stop the process? (I am using Ubuntu)

You can try it yourself: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo

[image: Terminal]

P.S.: I also cannot find the process via `ps -ef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a locally installed docker, you can run 'docker ps -a' to see all of your running images. Bazel pushes your image to your local docker repo, and tags it with 'bazel' I believe. You can use the docker kill command to kill your container.

For what it's worth, ctrl-c exits the run command for me in ubuntu 18.04 with bazel 1.x, using the bash shell.  (I never checked if it actually killed my container tho.)

Here is a ticket that might be relevant: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3519

In fact, the above issue is referenced by rules_docker here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/bb8da501955e5f7c1f704c50c0e4fce0193b2b2e/java/image.bzl#L406